# php curl request over ssl fails abruptly

Tags: php, curl

I'm running a curl request from a php script, very straight forward

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url-here');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

This works fine over http but as soon as i use https code execution doesn't pass the curl_exec command and i can't see what the error is. The client side i just receive a 'Connection Reset'.

It's worth noting it does the same thing if i use https://google.com.
Also worth noting that running this from the command like works fine so seems to be an issue running from a php script.

I've added the usual CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false and still no joy.

The same code does however work from my local machine so seems to be isolated to the server.

It's an amazon ec2 instance if that makes any difference.

Welcome any ideas.

Many thanks

Comment: So what does your error log file reveal?

Comment: Nothing. I've just solved it, i hadn't compiled curl --with-ssl  (rookie mistake!)

Comment: OK, though I am _very certain_ that in that case your error log file would tell you _exactly_ that. :-)

Comment: You'd think so wouldn't you. Nothing in my laravel log.

Comment: An undefined constant will _always_ be visible in the error log file.  _Unless_ you suppress it which is a bad idea in all cases. No idea what you mean by "laravel log file" btw. I asked for entries in your error log file. IN most cases that would be your http servers error log file, unless configured otherwise in your php settings.

Comment: No SSL support in cURL won't log any errors.  But checking `curl_getinfo` might yield some hints.  Connection reset essentially means the client couldn't speak SSL so the server closed the connection and the request fails.  Good job spotting that curl wasn't compiled with SSL support.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, curl wasn't compiled with SSL. Did this and all began to work.